# Android build drawing cashe bug

Tags: java, android

I have huge app with many different activities that used fragments via ActionBarSherlock.
Randomly when i launch new activity via intent i have this error:

```
08-08 18:22:12.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6438)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onAnimationStart(ViewGroup.java:1253)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onAnimationStart(ViewGroup.java:1253)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If somebody have any idea about how i can fix it please tell me. Thanks

Comment: By making sure your variable is not null! ;) Track what line is causing exception. Something on it isn't initialised correctly.

Comment: Variable is not null;) In stack trace there no lines from my code, only android SDK components.

Comment: I got same issue, but instead ActionbarSherlock i'm using android support libraries. I'm thinking it's firmware bug.